# How to write api request tests without launching server?

Tags: node.js, api, express, testing, fastify

It is possible to launch server on port and test it with library "supertest".
I'm wondering if it's possible to do the same without running a server?

Express app, the same as fastify app or others, takes request and response arguments from native node under the hood, like this:

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.end('hello\n');
});
```

So it should be possible to call that callback directly from tests.
How to get that callback? Is there any toolkit to help with constructing request and response objects for the callback?

The reason - just to make tests faster. As I don't want to test HTTP protocol and internals of node, I'd like to save time by skipping it.

Comment: Sure, you just hou have to create mock (but functional) `req` and `res` objects with all the right state and methods and then hook them well enough to see what the result is.

Comment: You can do that. But you need to differentiate between Unit Test and API Test.

You should do both,

If you're doing Unit Test, you should test middleware one by one, and mock the req, res object minimally as required.

If you're doing API test, then `supertest` or `newman` can be used. Somewhere in the test code, you will need to activate your server anyway. So you should be aware if there are any external API calls, if there is any, you can either let it make that call and wait, or just mock the results.

Comment: @Darkripper how do you know I can't differentiate between Unit Test and API Test (which may be called integration or e2e)? Should do both - I don't think so, if all code is covered with integration or e2e tests - no need for units.

Comment: @user2541867 You can call API Test as Integration or e2e as well (Depending on your application). It is best practice to do both Unit Test and Integration Test.

Unit Test do kind of force you to write ur code in chunks that is easily test-able, and more maintainable in the long run.

Doing just Integration Test might not check all the individual `unit` inside your code, but it still works. 

In the end, it is just preference.

You can read more here
https://martinfowler.com/articles/practical-test-pyramid.html

Comment: @Darkripper if I write beautiful and maintainable code by default, and integration tests covers all code - I can check that with coverage utils - then no need for units, right? Problem with units is that they requires much more effort, integration tests takes much less time to write and maintain. I bet there is no answer in the article why to do units if I can test everything faster without them, such articles are philosophical.

Comment: Deciding how to test your code is about balancing between the pros and cons of spending time to test.

So yeah, your view is definitely correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fastify has [this feature out of the box](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Testing/#benefits-of-using-fastifyinject):

```js
'use strict'

const { test } = require('tap')
const Fastify = require('fastify')

test('requests the "/" route', async t => {
  const fastify = Fastify()

  fastify.get('/', function (request, reply) {
    reply.send({ hello: 'world' })
  })

  const response = await app.inject({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/'
  })
  t.strictEqual(response.statusCode, 200, 'returns a status code of 200')
})
```

To moch the req/resp object it is used [light-my-request](https://github.com/fastify/light-my-request/#light-my-request) under the hood

Comment: That's awesome, thank you! I'm actually using fastify, I asked about express because they are very similar

Comment: Feel stupid because posted a question before checking docs...

Comment: Believe me, it's more than normal :)